# How to pivot single column table into 2 column table

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Here is my issue. I am taking an output of a split function , which is a single column table,
and need to transpose the out put into a 2 columns .

i.e.  let say I use

```sql
SELECT colNum = (((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))) - 1) % 2) + 1
      ,InsertData
FROM fn_split('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog test the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog test the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog test')`
```

which result in

```
|colNum|    InsertData                  |
|------|--------------------------------|
|1      |the quick brown fox jumped ove |
|------|--------------------------------|
|2      |r the lazy dog test the quick  |
|------|--------------------------------|
|1      |brown fox jumped over the lazy |
|------|--------------------------------|
|2      | dog test the quick brown fox  |
|------|--------------------------------|
|1      |jumped over the lazy dog test  |
|------|--------------------------------|
```

how do I turn this into  this

```
|-------------------------------|-------------------------------|
|           1                   |               2               |
|-------------------------------|-------------------------------|
|the quick brown fox jumped ove | r the lazy dog test the quick |
|-------------------------------|-------------------------------|
|brown fox jumped over the lazy | dog test the quick brown fox  |
|-------------------------------|-------------------------------|
|jumped over the lazy dog test  |-------------------------------|
|-------------------------------|-------------------------------|
```

I tried every way I know but nothing works.
I get a pivot but with empty cells in between.
I guess I am missing the common factor but I am not sure how to generate one for each set.

Comment: What is `fn_split`? Seems like the problem is that, but we don't have the code for it.

Comment: A "generic" split function would have a second parameter for the delimiter, the above doesn't contain one. Clearly it is splitting the value on something, but I've no idea what, and without the DDL we can't replicate your problem.

Comment: it is generic split function. I can not post code for it as it is proprietary for me. but in a gist, it takes any string and splits it into a chunks of specific length. actual function accepts second param determined the length you want. FN returns only a single column with split string. my select adds a row numbering to it.  now the next step I need is to take the output and turn it so each consecutive rows are pivoted into 2 columns. hence the row number resets on each third row.  but is there a way to also add group number that will reset every 2 rows?

Comment: @Larnu the problem is not the split function. Ignore that part of their question. They simply want to transpose the data so that column 1 has values where colNum = 1 and column 2 has values where colNum = 2, what their function does and how it works is not really relevant.

Comment: It is if it isn't returning the ordinal position of the split, @ChadBaldwin . And why I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT:

This is the new solution which is much better suited as a copy paste for your usage as I'm using a table value constructor which is similar to what you'd be dealing with using your `fn_split` function.

```sql
WITH cte_fnsplit AS (
    SELECT fn_split.InsertData
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1/0)
    FROM (
        VALUES ('the quick brown fox jumped ove')
            ,  ('r the lazy dog test the quick ')
            ,  ('brown fox jumped over the lazy')
            ,  (' dog test the quick brown fox ')
            ,  ('jumped over the lazy dog test')
    ) fn_split(InsertData)
)
SELECT x.rn, x.InsertData, x.NextValue
FROM (
    SELECT yt.rn, yt.InsertData
        , NextValue = LEAD(yt.InsertData) OVER (ORDER BY yt.rn)
    FROM cte_fnsplit yt
) x
WHERE x.rn % 2 = 1
```

In this case, you should be able to swap out my table value constructor with your fn_split function and get the results you're expecting.

It is worth noting, that by generating the row numbers outside of your `fn_split` function, that it's possible the rows will not get returned in a guaranteed order. Though probably unlikely, it is still possible to happen (similar to with `STRING_SPLIT()`)

My recommendation is, if you can, to add some sort of ordering column in the output of `fn_split`. It could be an identity value in a table variable you are building. Or it could simply be the starting point of the snippet in the string. This is likely information you already have, and likely won't impact the performance of the function.

---

### EDIT: This is the original old solution

So to veer a little from your original attempt, you could try something like
this:

```sql
WITH cte_fnsplit AS (
    SELECT fn_split.InsertData
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1/0)
    FROM (
        VALUES ('the quick brown fox jumped ove')
            ,  ('r the lazy dog test the quick ')
            ,  ('brown fox jumped over the lazy')
            ,  (' dog test the quick brown fox ')
            ,  ('jumped over the lazy dog test')
    ) fn_split(InsertData)
)
SELECT x.rn, x.InsertData, x.NextValue
FROM (
    SELECT yt.rn, yt.InsertData
        , NextValue = LEAD(yt.InsertData) OVER (ORDER BY yt.rn)
    FROM cte_fnsplit yt
) x
WHERE x.rn % 2 = 1
```

Returns:

```plaintext
| colNum | InsertData                     | NextValue                      | 
|--------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------| 
| 1      | the quick brown fox jumped ove | r the lazy dog test the quick  | 
| 3      | brown fox jumped over the lazy |  dog test the quick brown fox  | 
| 5      | jumped over the lazy dog test  | NULL                           |
```

---

### Explanation:

So I start off by looking up the "Next value" in the dataset using the `LEAD()` windowing function. This is almost like doing a self-join where `colNum = colNum + 1` type of thing.

Then after that, I stick it in a sub-query so I can give the `LAG()` function a name of `NextValue`.

Then I filter the result to only give me odd rows.

Comment: that would be perfect if it wasn't for power to be not restricting the use of any tempdb structures and such. if I can not do this in single select I will have to figure out the other way. I figure I ask incase some one has better idea than mine :-)

Comment: I'm only using tempdb because I needed to create a table with sample data. The query itself could be replaced using your split function. Give me a sec to update it to fit your situation better.

Comment: I am playing with using CTE  somehow , but can not make it work just yet

Comment: @vlad see latest update (might have to refresh page), I've updated my answer to use a CTE and to better suit your needs by eliminating the temp table.

Comment: I might also recommend that if `fn_split` is something you built yourself, you may want to consider including a OrderID column if that is information you have access to at the time, without hurting performance. The "OrderID" doesn't even necessarily have to be sequential (1,2,3) it could be the starting position of each segment.

Comment: Chad, you are the best.   CTE works perfectly for what I need to do. I don't know whay I was playing with PIVOT for this long. should have try CTE last night

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your splitter function returns the ordinal position, as that's what a good "generic" splitter does, then you can group on that with a little integer maths and use a modulus for the conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN OrdinalPosition % 2 = 1 THEN InsertData END) AS [1],
       MAX(CASE WHEN OrdinalPosition % 2 = 0 THEN InsertData END) AS [2]
FROM fn_split('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog test the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog test the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog test') 
GROUP BY (OrdinalPosition - 1) / 2;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ce84e258a4da2150093fe2b0963e3002)

Comment: no, the function returns nothing except a single column form the split parts.  I add the row count when select from the function. that said, I already have the code working using  Chad Baldwin answer from above. thanks

Comment: This is why I asked what it does, @vlad , because, like I said, a good "generic" splitter function tellsin you the ordinal position.